# Displaying Distance using HC-SR04 onto LCD

Tags: arm, embedded, mbed

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "TextLCD.h"
#include "HCSR04.h"

PinName pin_ECHO = D12; // Echo
PinName pin_TRIG = D11; // Trig

HCSR04 Ultra(pin_ECHO, pin_TRIG); // Sensor

// rs, rw, e, d0-d3
TextLCD lcd(D1, D2, D4, D5, D6, D7); 

float Ultra_cm(void);

int main() {
    uint16_t dist = 0;

    lcd.printf("   Ultra\n");
    lcd.printf(" Dist :    [cm]"); 

    while(1) {
        dist = Ultra_cm();
        lcd.locate(8, 1);
        lcd.printf("%3d", dist);
        wait(0.5);
    }
}

float Ultra_cm(void)
{
    Ultra.Measurment();

    while(!Ultra.isNewDataReady());

    return Ultra.getDistance_cm();
}
```

I'm trying to create a project where I have a ultrasonic sensor,HC-SR04, that will read the distance of an object and display it on a LCD(1602). This is the code I am using but when I compile it says the Ultra.Measurment() has no member and I don't know what I'm missing that is the issue. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated. The board I'm using is a Nucleo-L496ZG.

Comment: Do you want to share a link to your HCSR library?

Comment: https://os.mbed.com/users/SMART_CLEO/code/CLEO_ULTRASONIC//file/e7c4d23dbc05/HCSR04/

Comment: Looks like the library doesn't have a method called `Measurement()`. Perhaps, you wanted to call `startMeasurement()`?